# Struct hash for different types

Tags: swift, hash

I have a situation where I have 2 types, which **must** be structs for other reasons.

These two types are very similar, but are slightly different. However, their hashing & equality functions are exactly the same.

```
struct S1: Hashable {
    let data: String
    let otherData: String
    
    // ... Equality & Hash functions, both only use data
}
struct S2: Hashable {
    let data: String
    let otherData: Int
    
    // ... Equality & Hash functions, both only use data
}
```

Suppose I had a `Set` like this:

```
var set: Set<S1> = ...
```

How could I do a `contains` operation on `set`, but use a `S2` object instead, whilst maintaining the O(1) time complexity?

```
let obj: S2 = ...
set.contains(obj)
```

Is there a way to provide a custom equality & hashing object, or have some equivalent behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a protocol containing all the shared data, so both `S1` and `S2` go through the same hasher.

I created a `SharedData` protocol containing the shared properties (only `data` in this case) and gave it a `Hashable` implementation. Then `S1` and `S2` now conform to `SharedData`. It looks like this:

```
protocol SharedData: Hashable {
    var data: String { get }
}

extension SharedData {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
}

struct S1: SharedData {
    let data: String
    let otherData: String

    // ... Equality & Hash functions, both only use data
}
struct S2: SharedData {
    let data: String
    let otherData: Int

    // ... Equality & Hash functions, both only use data
}
```

And the comparison looks like this:

```
print(S1(data: "hi", otherData: "there").hashValue)
print(S2(data: "hi", otherData: 1).hashValue)

let set: Set<Int> = [S1(data: "Hello", otherData: "world!").hashValue, S1(data: "abc", otherData: "123").hashValue]

let obj2 = S2(data: "Hello", otherData: 0)
print(set.contains(obj2.hashValue))
```

> Prints:
>
> ```
> -5068166682035457964  // <- these change every program execution
> -5068166682035457964
> true
> ```

---

Unfortunately it's not possible to do the following, yet:

```
let set: Set<SharedData> = [S1(data: "Hello", otherData: "world!"), S1(data: "abc", otherData: "123")]
```

Error:

> Protocol 'SharedData' as a type cannot conform to 'Hashable'

I believe [SE-0309 (Unlock existentials for all protocols)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md) could fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I keep `set` as a `Set<S1>` though?

Comment: @Joe I'll carry on having a look if there is a better solution - but right now protocols (which you need because you can only use `struct`) are relatively limited in situations like this. See edit on end of answer

Comment: That's too bad. I hope apple implements that soon! But thank you for your help

Comment: @Joe Yep, unfortunately this is the only way for now. If you still need `S1` (fast), create a dictionary like `let dict: [Int: S1] = [a.hashValue: a, ...]` then check if `obj2` is in there with `print(dict[obj2.hashValue] != nil)`.